# Class has no member of a friend method

Tags: c++

im having trouble with this friend method upon calling the Union method an error of "class Set has no member named 'Union'. The program keep throwing an error regarding that Union function. I have no clue why does this friend declaration not work.
This is my Set class it uses a custom vector class, which is not relevant.

```
ifndef SET_H
#define SET_H
#include "myvector.h"

template <class T>
class Set
{
    public:
        Set();
        virtual ~Set();
        MyVector<T> & GetData();
        void Push_back(const T & element);
        void print();
        friend void Union(const Set<T> &set1, const Set<T> &set2, Set<T> &set3);

    private:
        MyVector<T> data;
};

template <class T>
Set<T>::Set()
{

}

template <class T>
Set<T>::~Set()
{

}
template <class T>
MyVector<T> & Set<T>::GetData()
{
    return data;
}

template <class T>
void Set<T>::Push_back(const T & element)
{
    data.push_back(element);
}

template <class T>
void Set<T>::print()
{
    data.print();
}

template <class T>
void Union(const Set<T> &set1, const Set<T> &set2, Set<T> &set3)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i<set1.data.count && j<set2.data.count)
    {
        if(set1.data[i] == set2.data[j])
        {
            set3.Push_back(set1.data[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if(set1.data[i] < set2.data[j])
        {
            set3.Push_back(set1.data[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            set3.Push_back(set2.data[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<set1.data.count)
    {
        set3.Push_back(set1.data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while(i<set2.data.count)
    {
        set3.Push_back(set2.data[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

This is my main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "set.h"
int main()
{
    Set<int> set1;
    Set<int> set2;
    Set<int> set3;
    set1.Push_back(1);
    set1.Push_back(2);
    set1.Push_back(4);
    set1.Push_back(1);
    set2.Push_back(3);
    set2.Push_back(5);
    cout << "printing set 1\n";
    set1.print();
    cout << "printing set 2\n";
    set2.print();
    set3.Union(set1,set2,set3);
    cout << "printing set 3 (union)\n";
    set3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Union` is a free function, not a member function. You call it like this: `Union(set1, set2, set3);`

Comment: i gave that a try and a new error is shows undefined reference to Union.

Comment: @Vincent The design is a bit strange. The free `Union` function should probably take only _two_ arguments (`set1` and `set2`) and _return_ the union of them, _by-value_.

Comment: @TedLyngmo this is one of a question from my past paper. It is the implement an algorithm using that parameters. Was not up to me, so I was just trying to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Each instantiation `Set<T>` has one specific friend: a `Union` function overloaded with parameters of type `Set<T>`. Your function template is not that friend. The common way to solve this problem is to define the friend function inside the class definition (yes, you can do that).

Comment: @molbdnilo so I move the implementation inline?

Comment: @Vincent Yes. You *could* also make a friend template, but then every instantiation of `Union` would be friends with every instantiation of `Set`, and that's usually not what you want.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for the help, I got it to work, as i have stated in another comment, this is just part of a practice question and the lecturer intended it to be this way.

Answer (score 0):

A free union function would normally take two arguments and return the union instead of having to instantiate the container that is supposed to receive the result and pass that as a parameter to the function.

You can still do it that way, but you'll need to declare the `friend` function as a function template.

In these examples, I'm returning the resulting `Set<T>` instead. Rewriting it to take `set3` as an argument instead is left as an exercice:

```
template <class T>
class Set
{
    public:       
        template<typename U> // make this a declaration of a function template 
        friend Set<U> Union(const Set<U>& set1, const Set<U>& set2);
};

template<typename T> // define it:
Set<T> Union(const Set<T>& set1, const Set<T>& set2) {
    Set<T> set3;

    // fill set3

    return set3;
}
```

Or easier: Define the `friend` function in your class definition directly:

```
template <class T>
class Set
{
    public:
        // Set will here be Set<T> automatically:
        friend Set Union(const Set& set1, const Set& set2) {
            Set set3;

            // fill set3

            return set3;
        }
};
```

In `main`:

```
Set<int> set3 = Union(set1, set2);
```